# Inter VLAN Routing - Dell S5212F with VLT

Tags: routing, dell, force10

I would like to know how to best set up Inter VLAN routing on a Dell S5212F cluster. (Version 10.4.3)

We have two S5212F Switchs which are connected via a VLT link.

Now I would like to know how to create a gateway that is present on both switches and which can be used for Inter VLAN Routing.

I basically have four VLANs. Three of them are allowed to communicate with each other.
The fourth VLAN I would like to route through the firewall.
This means that all packets that are not destined for the first three VLANs should be moved to the firewall, so that the decision what to do with the packets is made there.

Does anyone have an example configuration of how to handle such a scenario?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to your requirement create sub-interface for first 3 vlans in router and do inter-Vlan configuration in router and further connect L2 switch connecting router and L2 switch

The link connected between router and switch should be trunk link allowing all vlan from router to switch .  Post configuring inter -Vlan routing  .By default all Vlans will communicate among them , to control access between Vlans access -list need to be configured..

Create sub interfàce in firewall for fourth Vlan and connect firewall interfàce link to L2 switch ..

Further connect L2 switch to servers or laptops  and pass  vlans on L2 switch ports  as access ports  as per business requirements..